# Making figures in Latex

Tags: tikz-trees

Im trying to get help making the following figure in latex:

[image]

I know I have to use the tickz package. My document is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Decision theory}
\author{Me}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Did you already try to create it with TikZ?

Comment: [This](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/feature/trees/) could  help you.

Comment: It also can be done very easily with `pstricks`.

Comment: I've seen that guide, but I don't know how to make the bracket to the right of my figure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with `pstricks` and the `rcases` environment from `mathtools`. The strategy is very simply: wedefine an empty node on the left of the `rcases` environment, and two other empty nodes between  A and B of each pair, and connect the first node to each of the other two with a node connection:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Decision theory}
\author{Me}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb, xfrac}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{pst-node, auto-pst-pdf}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\pnode{a} % empty node
 \hspace{4em}
 \begin{rcases}
\pnode[-0.5ex,-1.5ex]{b} A : 1000 \\
    B: 400 \\[8ex]
\pnode[-0.5ex,-1.5ex]{r} A : 500 \\
    B: 600 \\
  \end{rcases}
\quad\Rightarrow\quad
\begin{matrix}
  \multirow{2}{*}{A: } & \sfrac{1}{2}& \sfrac{1}{2} \\
 & 1000 & 500 \\[2ex]
\multirow{2}{*}{B: } & \sfrac{1}{2}& \sfrac{1}{2} \\
 & 400 &600
\end{matrix}
\psset{labelsep=3pt}
\ncline{a}{b}\naput[nrot=:U]{\text{boom}}\nbput[nrot=:U]{ \sfrac{1}{2}}
\ncline{a}{r}\nbput[nrot=:U]{\text{recession}}\naput[nrot=:U]{ \sfrac{1}{2}}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]